# How does Judaism deal with God and paradoxes?

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, theology

How does Judaism deal with [paradoxes relating to the omnipotence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omnipotence_paradox) of God?

For example: Can God create a rock that he himself cannot lift?

Comment: Hello fakeID and welcome to Mi Yodeya! Thanks for bringing this deep philosophical question here.

Comment: I think this might fall under ["If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much."](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask)

Comment: Also, the specific paradox given as an example is not a paradox. If we assume that God cannot violate the laws of logic, there is no problem with answering "no" to that question, since limiting God to the logically possible does not undermine His omnipotence.

Comment: Related: [Reconciling the evidence for the Uncertainty Principle with belief in an omniscient G-d](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/9735/883).

Comment: If you were to say "assuming God is Omnipotent", then you can create a valid hypothetical question. But Logic is essential in creating any good argument. But -"How does Judaism deal with paradoxes relating to the omnipotence of God?" gives respect to their belief without expecting proof perhaps in the same intent as a hypthetical question. The same is true for the Koran and all its Beliefs. May Allah be merciful and (his followers) more Logical....

Comment: Similar: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/27126

Answer (score 32):

Questions relating to God's omnipotence were discussed at length by the Rishonim in the Middle Ages in such great works as Saadia Gaon's "Emunos V'deos", Rambam's "Moreh Nevuchim", Ralbag's "Milchemes Hashem", and others. The consensus among them (in opposition to the authorities cited in [@HodofHod's answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/16311/489)) is that **God cannot violate the rules of logic**. This prevents such paradoxes such as the one you mentioned, as well as other like "Can God assume physical form?", "Can God create another God?", etc.

Why does this not undermine God's omnipotence? Because saying that God cannot do X, where X is a logically impossible task, does not limit God's power any more than saying that a person cannot drink a Wednesday (h/t @DoubleAA) limits that person's power. The verb "drink" simply does not make sense with "Wednesday" as an object. Similarly, the verb "do" does not work with "X" as an object, if X is logically impossible. Here's how Saadia Gaon says it ([Emunos V'deos, Ch. 2](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=38322&st=&pgnum=54)):

> ואין היא משבחתו ומפארתו אלא בתבונה ומישרים, לא בגוזמא והבל כמי שעושה החמשה יותר מן העשרה מבלי הוסיף עליהם, שמכניס תבל בחללה של טבעת מבלי צמצם האחת והרחב השניה, שמחזיר אמש לקדמותו, שכל אלה הבל הם. אפשר ישאלונו כמה מן המינים באותו ענין. אנו משיבים להם הוא יכול לכל דבר ואלו מה ששאלו, לא דבר הוא, הבל הוא וההבל אינו ולא כלום
>
> *His praises and His glorifications are only with understandable and upright things, not with exaggeration and absurdity such as "He who can make five more than ten without adding to it", or "He who can fit the entire world into the hole of a ring without shrinking the former or enlarging the latter", or "He who can make the past into the future", for all these things are absurdities. Perhaps several heretics will ask us about this. We will respond to them "He has the ability to do all things, but that which you mentioned - that is not a thing; it is an absurdity, and an absurdity is not anything."*

Comment: +1, Good answer, and thanks for bringing the dissenting view!

Comment: +1, Thank you for this clear, obvious, and well sourced answer to this famous absurdity. The fact that people call it a paradox annoys me to no end.

Comment: @HodofHod - dissenting view?

Comment: @Fred, To [his answer](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/16311/489).

Answer (score 18):

According to some Jewish authorities, especially Kabbalists and [Chassidic Rebbes](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=15895&st=&pgnum=377), G-d does not have to obey the rules of logic, since they are just another creation of His. As [I wrote to a similar question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/10051/883):

> As the Creator of all things, including, but not limited to, time, the "laws" of physics, logic, and existence itself, G-d is not bound by any of them. Can G-d create a rock that He is unable to pick up? Yes, and He can also pick it up. How? Why? Because logic does not apply to G-d. Go argue with that (you can't; argument requires logic :-D).

---

From [Chabad.org](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/693352/jewish/Can-Gd-Create-a-Rock-Thats-Too-Heavy-for-Him-to-Lift.htm)'s "Can G‑d Create a Rock That's Too Heavy for Him to Lift?"

> I've provided a long-winded answer for the inquisitive mind. Sometimes, however, it's not a philosopher asking the question, it's just some smart-aleck. But the smart-aleck also deserves an answer. So you can simply say, "Sure G‑d can create a rock so heavy that even He cannot lift it. G‑d can do anything. And He could even lift that rock that He cannot lift as well."
>
> That'll send 'em flying. And it's not untrue. Because it's simply saying that G‑d does not fit into any of our standard ways of thinking. G‑d is not a thing—He is the source of all things. The tools of measurement of things simply do not apply to Him.

Comment: Ah, commentless downvotes. How I've missed you.

Comment: Violating the laws of physics is not the same thing as violating logic. The letter you linked to in Igros Kodesh (along with the example of the Aron) refers to the former not the latter.

Comment: I also heard that since a rock that G-d can't lift cannot exist, asking such a question is like asking if G-d can create a SDFSFAFGSFGFGA? Now answer that question...

Comment: @ShmuelBrin, That is essentially the same as [my answer](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/16315/489).

Comment: @Fred is Math considered logic or physics?

Comment: @ShmuelBrin - To say that something is 10 feet tall and 20 feet tall at the same time violates the laws of physics. To say that something is *only* 10 feet tall and *only* 20 feet tall at the same time violates logic.

Comment: @Fred You are mistaken. In that letter the Rebbe is bringing a view that _clearly_ disagrees with R' Saadya Gaon's. "כל יכול כפשוטו" means even that which is _not_ "מעגליך על  פי שכל".

Comment: @HodofHod Incomprehensible and illogical are two different things.

Comment: @Fred And therefore? G-d is both. And not both. When it says that G-d is capable of things that are not "מעגליך על פי שכל" it means that He can do things which are illogical, and therefore, incomprehensible. This opinion says that G-d is "כל יכול כפשוטו". That means that if you say "Can G-d ..?" the answer is "yes", and if you ask "Does G-d have to ...?" the answer is "no". Simple enough.

Comment: @HodofHod The Rebbe was disagreeing with the [Ba'al HaAkeidah](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14340&st=&pgnum=177) who takes the position that God's omnipotence does not extend to things that are incomprehensible, like an object having inconsistent dimensions. כל יכול כפשוטו means that God can even perform incomprehensible acts, such as making the *aron* dimensionless and dimensioned simultaneously. Those two things are physically incompatible and incomprehensible, but they are not logically impossible. The letter doesn't suggest that omnipotence violates logic.

Comment: Math is the basis of all Physics and all Boolean Algebra we use in Philosophy Logic and Fallacy.

Comment: @TonyStewart - Lists of certain event possibilities that are assumed to be exhaustive and mutually exclusive from a physical standpoint may not be so from a metaphysical standpoint. Only when we assume that two events are mutually exclusive do we have a logical dilemma when faced with their simultaneous existence. That's why a dimensioned, dimensionless ark does not pose a logical dilemma.

Comment: @Fred You're saying that the Baal HaAkeidah disagrees with the Aron both having and not having spatial dimensions? (I can't read that link right now.)

Comment: @HodofHod Not explicitly, but the Rebbe used the example of the *aron* as a basis for disputing the Ba'al HaAkeidah's understanding of omnipotence in general.

Comment: @Fred I fail to see how you can read any limitations into "כל** יכול כפשוטו**". I would think that if the Rebbe had intended the same meaning as R' Saadia (that that which is logically impossible is not possible for Him, and is still not a limitation), that would have been much clearer. It's clear enough that when the Rebbe says "כל יכול כפשוטו" he means without exceptions, else he surely would have included them in his response. (Saying that the limitation of logic is implied doesn't hold up. The Rebbe is explaining what "כל יכול" means, he wouldn't leave that out.)

Comment: @HodofHod - Logic does not impose restrictions or limitations on what can happen; it is descriptive rather than proscriptive. It is the means of discarding nonsense and absurdity. If someone can't eat a day of the week, it is not a deficiency in their capability - it is simply a matter of definition. A defining property of a day of the week is that it eating has no *shaichus* to it. It would be absurd to suggest otherwise. If someone would have the ability to eat a day of the week, that would say nothing about their ability...

Comment: @HodofHod - ...It would only mean that we have redefined what "day of the week" means.  R' Saadia's words are a *davar pashut*; of course logical integrity does not limit omnipotence. There's no reason to assume that anyone would hold that it does, or that כל יכול כפשוטו somehow means that logic gets thrown out the window.

Comment: @HodofHod If God creates something that cannot be lifted, it is no longer a rock. God can't create a rock that can't be lifted because lifting is _by the definition of rocks_ shayach to rocks. If you redefine "rock" to include this new thing, then God can create a rock that he can't lift. It *only* is a matter of definitions and has nothing to do with ability or omnipotence.

Comment: @Fred. The concept of G-d not being limited to sechel and logic is replete throughout Chassidus/Kabbalah and even rishonim (as the Rebbe states). The link to Chabad.org is indicative of that. The idea that the Rebbe would just ignore that part of  "כל יכול " in his letter even while redefining the entire idea is absurd (IMO). Additionally, I'm not sure that Chassidus/Kabbalah draws much of a distinction between incomprehensibility and illogicality. Both would be "above" sechel and chochmah.

Comment: If you want to know more about why the Rebbe holds this, and what exactly his sources are, you should ask someone who is more well versed in the Rebbe's/Chassidus' teachings than I am. But that he held this is certain. Ok, I'm done discussing this. Thanks for the discussion :).

Comment: @HodofHod - Of course the concept of God isn't limited by sechel, but we must always think logically about aspects of scenarios that are within the scope of our understanding. The OP imposed limits on the scenario by introducing "rocks" and "lifting", both of which are inherently circumscribed by their definitions.

Comment: @Fred Hmmm... while there are certain rules that G-d chooses to operate under in this world, it would still be a problem to say "G-d can't...". Better say "G-d doesn't...".

Comment: @HodofHod - The [Rashba](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1376&st=&pgnum=190&hilite=) is the rishon that the Rebbe directly referenced because he disagrees with the Ba'al HaAkeidah's main point that the conflicting nature of man's soul and animal aspects preclude God's ability to create mankind in a manner that it would never sin. The Rashba writes that is not true because God can suspend the rules of nature as he wishes. Further, the [Tzemach Tzedek](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=21246&st=&pgnum=74) that the Rebbe quoted cites and agrees with R' Saadia...

Comment: @HodofHod - ...that God's interactions with the world are bound by logical constraints and that this is not considered a restriction on His omnipotence. An example that he gives is that a year, by it's definition, cannot have 600,000 days. (Furthermore, the Tzemach Tzedek writes that this is "*l'chol ha'deios*"). Only God's essence, he writes, is totally free from all logical constraints.

Comment: Did anyone in 19 comments mention that Logic is a human invention and therefore only humans are bound by logic.

Comment: @mochinrechavim I was under the impression that logic was G-d's invention, and therefore does _not_ bind Him.

Comment: @HodofHod What put you under that impression? Everything is apart of Hashem, but he gave humans free will and we used it to create this "logic" idea and then try to work Hashem into our logic plan. Is it logical that the Red Sea split? Scientist try to explain it so it fits logic.

Comment: @mochinrechavim But humans did not create the "logic" (not the best word choice IMO) that prevents seas from splitting on a regular basis. G-d did.

Comment: @HodofHod Logic is the philosophical study of valid reasoning. If it isnt logical then it is a miracle. Man tries to fit our omnipresent G-d into a little man made box. Hashem creates EVERYTHING. This isnt what we are talking about. We are talking about the Chochma of Greek Philosophy which says that everything must follow their definition of nature which a Jew does not ascribe to.

Comment: @mochinrechavim Ah. So the fact that we have anthropomorphically given those same limitations to G-d is the "human invention" you were referring to. But the fact that we and the rest of the world have those limitations (except when G-d wills otherwise) is _G-d's_ invention.

Comment: @HodofHod That sounds about right. We are talking about a very lofty idea. The Mitteler Rebbe (Chabad Rebbe No. 2) has a sefer called Shar HaYichud. It is considered to be the Keys to understanding Chassidus. It discusses this concept by explaining Seder Histalshelus and how Hashem functions and interacts in this world. Once you realize that Ohr Ayin Sof and the Rock on the ground are both the same level of G-dliness abeit one being concealed to a greater level then the question isn't so difficult.

Comment: In his Reader, R' Aryeh Kaplan zt"l says this is a machloqes betwen the Rambam and the Ramchal. The Rambam says the illogical is meaningless -- G-d can no more make a round square than He can make a flugleek. They're just a bunch of sounds that don't amount to anything. The Ramchal says what you describe here. Logic is a creation, and therefore the Creator isn't subject to it.

Comment: Personal 2c: Since the 19th century, we found that there is no one system of logic -- Boolean Logic (including Aristotle's), Fuzzy Logic, the very small seems to obey Quantum Logic, other theoretical logics... Makes me inclined to go with the Ramchal.

Answer (score 8):

I heard someone once say that you can begin to understand God only when you acknowledge that you can never fully understand God.

Part of faith in God is understanding that we are finite and unable to ever understand the infinity of God.

So I guess the answer is that God is all powerful and we dont fully understand how that manifests itself in our world we can only have faith in that He is there and all-powerful.

Comment: Oh, thanks for saving Him out this stupid discussion. (Get me right - I appreciate the question and I ponder overt it myself sometimes, I appreciate other answers as well, but I think only this particular answer brings the whole discussion into proportions).

Comment: I agree wholeheartedly with the first two sentences of this answer. It is true that no human can fully understand God. As Rambam famously wrote, "If I could understand everything about Him, I would *be* Him." However, this is said with respect to God's **omniscience**, not His omnipotence, which is the property the OP asked about.

Comment: To say we don't understand is another way of proving my point. We are making an assumption, based only on Belief. No offense to Rambam, but If I could do the impossible and say it is true, does not prove the impossible is possible. Hence a fallacious argument.

Answer (score 8):

To add a bit in the same vein as [Jake's answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/16315/1442):

This is not a real paradox; it is simply a matter of definitions. "He who can make five more than ten without adding to it" is a great example of this; making five more than ten requires adding by the very definition of the ordinal system. A rock is by definition material, and lifting is by definition an act applicable only to the material.

Since God is omnipotent, he can lift anything that is definitionally subject to lifting. Therefore, to put it clumsily, "God cannot create such a rock" because God would by definition have to make it something other than a rock in order for it to no longer be subject to lifting.

Comment: This is what I described in https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/16307/how-does-judaism-deal-with-god-and-paradoxes/16311#comment308289_16311 as the Rambam's positoin.

Answer (score 6):

I don't have any source on this but my understanding has always been that these paradoxes stem from human perceptions and interaction with the world. The hardest thing about understanding the nature of god is that it is, by definition, beyond understanding. We use a term like "omnipotence" and impose on it our version of what that means and what paradoxical limitations could be applied to it. This simply points out our inability to grasp what god is.

When people ask me that particular paradox I simply say "Yes. And then he lifts it."

Answer (score 6):

In the back of [the first volume of Chassidut Me'vueret on the Holidays](http://store.chassidus.com/item_detail.php?item_id=4525), there is a discussion similar to this. The question asked there is, if, as the Maharal of Prague says (In his sefer Gevurot Hashem), G-d is simply whole, without any parts or definable qualities, how can we give G-d descriptions, like Merciful, etc.? How can we say the Sefirot (at least in the world of Atzilut), which are specific attributes, are an extension of G-d's light?

The answer given is based on the statement in the Avodat HaKodesh: "Just as G-d has the power of the infinite, He also has the power of the finite. For if we were to say that G-d was only infinite, and not finite, we would be limiting G-d's completion."

In other words, to say G-d can't limit himself is itself limiting G-d.

It then goes on to explain that when we say G-d is infinite, we're saying that G-d has all the advantages of everything without the deficiencies (in Hebrew this is expresses as Shlemut HaKol). Everything in the world has an advantages and corresponding deficiencies. For example, a big car might be safer in accidents, but it takes more gas and needs bigger parking spaces.

G-d has the upside of everything without the disadvantages. Going back to the Avodat Hakodesh, G-d is infinite. If you tell me that there is a deficiency in being infinite (i.e. not being able to be finite when it is advantageous to do so), I will tell you that G-d can make himself finite too, when he needs to. That finiteness is not a limitation, but an expression of his infiniteness and completion.

Here is a [chapter of Heaven on Earth](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/294299/jewish/The-Nature-of-G-d.htm), by Rabbi Faitel Levin which explains this all a lot better and more thoroughly than I just did.

---

So, to say G-d cannot create a rock so big he can't lift doesn't take away from G-d's completion, it doesn't mean G-d is deficient. Not being able to lift a rock is a deficiency, and G-d has none.

Comment: "to say G-d can't limit himself is itself limiting G-d": no it isn't. God can't limit the unlimited not because he is limited in powers, but because it's not a thing to do, just as one can't drink a Wednesday. If something isn't a thing to do, then it can't be done. God can do everything that can be done; I don't see how that is limiting.

Comment: @DoubleAA: G-d is unlimited, without any parts or descriptions - MahaRal of Prague. yet Kabalah says G-d contracted himself to create the world. G-d limited his infiniteness, to create a reality where G-dliness is concealed. - I added a link to a chapter for Rabbi Levin's book. See there for an analogy of 4.5-volt electric source, where being more limited is advantageous.

Comment: I think he is confused then: it's not that the 4.5 V battery is stronger, it's that the tape recorder is weaker. That is certainly clear from a physics perspective. More energy is more energy. It is not advantageous for the tape recorder to be unable to handle large amounts of energy.

Comment: @DoubleAA: exactly, therefore to blast the device with unadulterated power directly from the source would not be better, but worse. Limiting the power to the device would be better.

Comment: No, increasing the capacity of the device to handle power would be better.

Comment: (Don't you see how it's all a matter of perspective?)

Comment: We can look both ways at which is better and which is worth, but in physics, energy is defined as the capacity to do work. Maybe in one instance you can show how reducing energy would be a temporary fix, but in general the best solution is always the one that increases total useful energy, ie more work can be done.

Comment: Consider our case: in your solution we have a working tape-recorder; in my solution we have a super-tape-recorder that can play infinite tapes at infinite speeds at infinite volumes etc. Which of those two solutions is "better"? Subjectively, possibly neither if all you need is a regular tape-recorder. But most would agree that in general the more powerful one is better as it is more useful in more situations.

Comment: So too God: you can limit God to achieve a specific solution based on your current needs, but isn't a limitless God overall better?

Comment: @DoubleAA: Everything we are discussing is in relation to how G-d actually created the world, not how he could have created it. There is a standard tape recorder, now how do we power it. G-d wasn't forced to create the world this way, but did. Somewhere it is explained that G-d created the world (as explained in Kabbalah) using logical progressions (Seder Hishtalshelut), so that we would be able to understand it (as much as it could be understood by the human mind). It is within this framework that our discussion takes place

Comment: Ok... So within the framework, I still don't see how God can limit the unlimited. How is that not like drinking a Wednesday?

Comment: @DoubleAA: Because we're explaining unlimited as the ultimate of completion. That includes the completion (advantages) of infinite, and the completion of finite.

Comment: So if it was to God's advantage to do so, he could drink a Wednesday?

Comment: @DoubleAA: Can G-d create a big rock, sure? Can G-d limit himself so that he can't pick it up? What's the advantage in that? - That's different the drinking a wednesday, which would be answered by jake's answer: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/16315/603

Comment: How is an infinitely powerful being not being able to lift a rock more logical than drinking a Wednesday?

Comment: @DoubleAA: Because something being heavy is something we can relate to, drinking Wednesday is just gibberish. Take for example, our sages' comment, "all in in the hands of heaven except for the fear of heaven". Is G-d truly  powerless over our fear of heaven? Only because He chooses to be.

Comment: @Menachem I'm not sure what your last analogy has to do with the argument. I accept He can choose not to do things within the realm of things He can do. I don't think creating a rock He can't lift is in that realm. It's not something He can do because it is gibberish.

Comment: @DoubleAA: I edited to my answer to hopefully clarify what I was trying to say.

Comment: @Menachem do you have an exact source for the Maharal?

Comment: @Bochur613: I've never learned it inside, but a quick google search finds a discussion of it here, in Chapter 67: http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pagefeed/hebrewbooks_org_14204_304.pdf -- Here it is said that it is brought in the Preface: http://chabadlibrary.org/books/default.aspx?furl=/zz/dm/1/24/47a -- My guess it is a little bit of a running theme, since as explained in the second link, the Maharal is disagreeing with the Rambam's definition

Comment: @Fred could you direct to the link of the Tzemach Tzedek you posed where you can find where he says what you summarized? Thanks

Answer (score 5):

i'm surprised that none of the answers have addressed the fact that God himself creates and abides by these contradictions. Things like God's omniscience and [human free will](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/856/do-we-really-have-free-choice) or the kabbalistic concept of tzimtzum indicate that there are already plenty of "immovable rocks". from these examples it would seem clear that God puts limits on himself and, from our human perspective, abides by those limits. How this can be reconciled with our definition of omnipotence and "God" seems to take for granted that we understand completely what those latter two terms mean, which i don't believe is the case. If we admittedly do not know everything there is to know about God is it not the height of hubris to believe that we have "caught" him in a contradiction?

Comment: Re "none of the answers have addressed the fact that God himself creates and abides by these contradictions", see [Menachem's answer](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/16316).

Comment: sources for this answer can be found here - http://kankannelam.blogspot.com/2011/12/can-god-do-impossible.html