# Can God destroy Himself?

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, death, theology

I was thinking about it lately.

**If God can do everything, can He destroy Himself?**

Is there something about this possibility in any of the holy books?

Comment: This might sound like a facetious question, but why is it necessary to believe that God can do *everything*? Our sources are replete with passages that concern his disappointment or regret. Your hashkafa might tell you otherwise, but I see nothing in Tanakh or the early rabbinic literature to lead me to such a perspective. Existence appears to be a necessary quality of God, along with his singularity.

Comment: related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/16307/how-does-judaism-deal-with-god-and-paradoxes

Comment: @ShimonbM Can you give an example of His disappointment or regret?

Answer (score 21):

This kind of question is addressed by Maimonides in his *Guide for the Perplexed* (3:15), in which he states that we cannot ascribe to God the ability to do that which is impossible, thus, "it is impossible that God should produce a being like Himself, or annihilate, corporify, or change Himself. The power of God is not assumed to extend to any of these impossibilities."

It is important to understand that this does not actually entail any limitation on the power of God (as Maimonides states later). This is because the real issue here is that the questions are fundamentally nonsense. God cannot destroy - or duplicate - Himself any more than He can create a triangle with four corners. The only way we can ask either question is if we fail to understand the meanings of the words we are using.

Comment: The "nonsense" you mention towards the end is actually a better translation than "impossible", even though that is strictly what he wrote he meant it in terms of nonsensical. As in, "it is impossible to conceptualize such a concept", not that "it cannot be done".

Comment: @AviD A triangle with four corners not, but why is it nonsense for God Himself to "limit" his capabilities, i.e. in destroying himself or "expand" in creating himself?

Comment: @Yehoshua because a basic fundamental aspect of God, is that he *exists*. Thus, if it were possible that God were to be destroyed, therefore resulting in God's non-existence - then this is not "God that must exist". The same goes for His singularity - creating another such as Himself would nullify the basic tenet of "only one". With these aspects being fundamental, these questions then become the same as the four cornered triangle - we are trying to force him to change the basic concept. A different rose by the same name...

Comment: @AviD Of course this is all based on the acceptance of the 13 principles as absolute truth and without argument  among other rishonim. Although perhaps these points are without argument. But I understand what you are saying.

Answer (score 4):

I believe that this question is based on a premise that illustrates a shallow understanding of what G-d is. The question assumes that the rules of logic are somehow inherently there, and G-d is bound by them. If that would be the case, if we would say that G-d is unlimited then He would be bound to being unlimited, and could not also be limited - because logically something which is unlimited cannot also be limited. Another form that this question often takes is the famous "Can G-d create a rock so heavy that He can't pick up".

In fact, not only did G-d create the world, but he created logic too. He is therefore not bound by the constraint of logic. Yes, logically it is not possible to pick up something that is too heavy to pick up - but G-d was the one who made the rock, the concept of heaviness and the rule that something that is too heavy cannot be lifted. So the answer is yes, He could create such a rock, and He could pick it up too. Another example: G-d created a world in which one plus one equals two - He could just as possibly have made a world were one plus one is three.

The is famously expressed in a Kabbalistic work called "[Avodas Hakodesh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meir_ben_Ezekiel_ibn_Gabbai)" (Section I, ch. 8):

> אור אין סוף הוא שלימותא דכולא, כשם שיש לו כח בבלתי בעל גבול כך יש לו כח בגבול, שאם תאמר יש לו כח בבלתי בעל גבול ואין לו כח בגבול הרי אתה מחסר שלימותו ואין סוף הוא שלימותא דכולא - Just as the Infinite One possesses power with an infinite dimension, so too does He possess power with a finite dimension. For if you were to say that He possesses infinite power but not finite power, you would detract from His perfection [for there would be an area, the realm of finitude, that would remain outside the context of G-dliness -- which is impossible], for G-d is the ultimate perfection.

In other words, since G-d is the ultimate perfection, there is no advantage that He lacks. In logical terms, two opposite advantages can be mutually exclusive (How can something be limited and unlimited at the same time), but for G-d that is not a constraint.

So to answer your question: Can G-d destroy Himself? G-d possesses any advantage that there might be in being able to self-destroy, but at the same time this does not contradict with His ability to exist forever.

Comment: Hmm, so... yes or no?

Comment: Yes AND No. :-)

Comment: Very much disagree with your analogy. God can create a rock so heavy that he cannot pick it up, and then he cannot pick it up. But that's not a limitation of God, it's a limitation of the rock. So too, God cannot play the first move in a game of chess and get checkmate immediately. None of the twenty possible opening moves results in checkmate. That's a limitation of chess, not of God. And yet God could invent the game of chess. Likewise, he can invent something else, the rules of which prevent his circumventing them. Like a square circle, etc.

Comment: [cont.] In this case, God's inability to destroy himself represents a limitation in the existence of God. It is a more profound paradox than the one with the rock.

Comment: So you're saying He can and can't destroy Himself? That implies I am a unicorn.

Comment: I think he is saying that applying a human understanding of logic and choice to a transcendent being is doomed to failure. Expecting god to conform to my ideas of "can" and "cannot" especially as exclusive categories is to impose the limits of my understanding (and possibly the limits of the physical universe) on a being which we consider unlimited. It is the ultimate "dibeir hakatuv" as ALL words and phrases in human-speak are by definition limitations on the infinite divine.

Comment: Again, I am not asking if we can create unlimited heavy rock. I am asking if God, who is almighty, can destroy himself, if he wants to.

Comment: @Derfder, I think that is clear, the question raised by this answer is whether there is a philosophical difference between your question and whether a God can create a rock too heavy for Him to lift.

Comment: @Dan what are you saying? What is a non human form of logic? Logic is logic. Language has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Logic is a function of human understanding. Communication is a form of assimilation of fact through limited understanding and encoding into human (finite) language. Logic is the system we impose on our understanding and our communication and is a lens through which we understand our universe. If humans didn't exist, would logic? Not if it is a system of understanding via the human experience. And the limiting language which colors and is colored by understanding makes the process even more constrained.

Comment: @Dan Logic wouldn't exist without humans, and logic doesn't exist with humans. It's not a thing. But nothing with or without humans can ever be illogical. It is not just a function of our understanding; it precedes Understanding. I think you are confusing logical impossibility with physical impossibility. The latter is a function of our understanding based on the world we live in, and we project it into our ideas.

Comment: This post is self-declared nonsense. How can nonsense answer a question? It's meaningless.

Comment: @Dan Can God create a universe? According to you the answer is yes and no. How does that square with Bereishit?

Comment: @DoubleAA Ultimately, you are right -- by using language to say god "creates" we impose the human construct of creating. By asserting that something happened, we open up to the possibility that it didn't or couldn't happen. This is an inherent problem of trying to describe the infinite through the finite. The torah narrative is written for us to understand the process, not for us to think that it somehow captures the essence of god's nature.

Comment: @DoubleAA I think you are confusing human understanding of the universe with some sort of transcendent and objective Understanding which you say creates the limit of logical possibility. The moment you stick a human into the equation you defy that transcendent and replace it with our version of the transcendent. God's behavior can defy what we consider logic and still not be, ultimately, "illogical".

Comment: @Dan God's behavior can't be ultimately illogical because it can't defy what He and us consider logic. What is human or finite that prevents a fuller understanding of material implication than is achieved through modus ponens?

Comment: but the logic that god 'has to follow' (?) cannot be external to god and imposed on him, so any behavior he "does" must be logical even if it goes against what WE think is logical.

Comment: This is not really relevant anyway. LazerA already answered the question. This post, while being nonsense, doesn't even directly address the question at hand. It's preposterous and borderline kefira to suggest God could destroy Himself.

Comment: @Dan Right. That's why nothing he does is illogical for us or Him. If anything He does goes against what WE think is logical, then I am a unicorn.

Comment: @DoubleAA, Didn't this argument occur already with Menachem [here](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/16316/489)? As illogical as the assumption of logic being a human construct is, it's not really possible to disprove without using logic which is apparently futile. Best to just say "I like ponies" and be done with it.

Comment: @DoubleAA Thanks for your kind words ;-) Not sure what you mean by "LazerA already answered the question".  Since when is there only one right answer in Yiddishkiet? Is this the only time Kabbalah and Chakirah have divergent approaches to a question?

Comment: @Michoel What does Kabbalah have to do with it? Are you saying your answer isn't nonsense (technically speaking)?

Comment: @jake But I _do_ like ponies! It kind of did. But Dan is a different person and perhaps he had something else to offer. This answer should really just be migrated there to the question is seems to be responding to.

Comment: @DoubleAA Avodas Hakodesh is a work in Kabbalah. My answer is that you are applying logical constraints to a being that supersedes logic.

Comment: @Michoel So God can and can't create a universe? He can and can't create you? He can and can't create a river? He can and can't think? He can and can't do anything Good? He can and can't divide Himself into multiple Gods? ||| It's being a work of Kabbalah doesn't make this into the position of anyone who learns Kabbalah (at least you haven't shown or claimed that). It could just be a coincidence, especially because I don't see any distinctive Kabbalistic reasoning (sefirot or something).

Comment: To borrow from some other examples being thrown around; G-d could create a four corned triangle, and win a checkmate on the first move of the game. He created the rule that triangles must have three corners, and that step two must  come after step one so He is not bound by them. Of course that's unfathomable, but then again He created logic.

Comment: @Michoel So you agree God can't create the universe? Yes or no.

Comment: @DoubleAA The concept of "can" that is opposite to "cannot" was also a created by Him.

Comment: @Michoel That wasn't a yes or no.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7916/discussion-between-michoel-and-double-aa)

Answer (score 3):

If the siddur qualifies as a "holy book", then in אדון עולם it says that Hashem is בלי ראשית בלי תכלית which I would translate as "without beginning, without end".

Chief Rabbi Sacks says in his commentary on siddur that "the siddur is our tutorial in belief".

Following Derfder's comment below:

The Ramchal starts Derekh Hashem [as follows:](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=38531&st=&pgnum=11)

> Every Jew must know that there exists a first Being **without
>   beginning or end** who brought all things into existence and continues
>   to sustain them. This being is God.

Comment: I was thinking about it exactly like that too, but I am not sure according to my further studies if it is like that. That's why I am asking, you know.

Comment: That's lifted almost straight from Maimonides. The very beginning of Mishne Torah

Comment: @Derfder ping see addition to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Easy answer: no.

Where does it say "G-d can do anything?"

Go back to Maimonides' 13 principles of faith:

"... that He is the creator and director of everything created, and He alone has done, currently does, and will do *all that is done*."

"All that is done" does not include theoretical paradoxes!

(Yes I realize there's a place in the High Holiday liturgy where G-d is referred to as *hakol yachol*, "all-capable", but that's the nutshell version. You want the nitty-gritty, go back to Maimonides' formulation.)

Let's take it further: we also believe that G-d is absolutely one, and that G-d is non-physical. "Can G-d make Himself physical? Can G-d cut Himself into two?" The answer to all these questions is no.

If it makes you feel better, [Rabbi Yosef Gavriel Bechhofer](http://rygb.blogspot.com) has a fascinating syllabus for lectures on the Thirteen Principles, which does include a bullet point on "can G-d create a rock too heavy for Him to lift?"

Comment: Sorry, but I am not asking about how heavy can a rock be ;). I am asking about if it is possible that God can destroy himself. Your example with creating an unlimited heavy thing has nothing to do with dissolving things themselves or if you wish God entropy, which can probably be forced from outer or induced/initiated from within (God itself).

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to offer a more philosophical/logical answer, but essentially I'm only  providing you with hopefully more simple means of understanding the reasoning behind other answers appearing here.

Please allow me to tackle the title question:

> Can God destroy himself?

The particular issue with this question is that by asking it you are ascribing (or assuming) a men-like, natural qualities to God - thus, given you believe in a supernatural God, the question itself is nonsense. Let me explain:

> By worldly logic, in order to destroy himself, God first needs to exist - only then he can destroy himself. Thus you are assuming God exists in time. If such is the case, who created time?

From here there are two options:

- God doesn't exist in time.
- A God greater than God created time (essentially making the former the real God, who doesn't exist in time).

Regardless of which one you pick, both derive at the same conclusion: God doesn't exist in time. And if so, cause and effect are not part of his existence. And so asking if God can destroy himself (cause) and thus cease to exist (effect) is complete nonsense.

Removing time, cause and effect from the Godly realm also solves the question: who created God? For if there's no time, God always existed.

Even if God could destroy himself, in an existence not based on cause and effect he could 'undo' his own destruction or carry on existing despite destroying himself. The same logic that applies to us does not apply to God - in his existence everything is possible, even having no limits and all the limits. This is pretty much what God is about.

Now allow me to seal this off with a question. Is this a nonsense question:

> Did God created the world?

Please note that I'm not asking if God created the world, I'm asking if asking the question is a valid thing to do.

Comment: Izhak, welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks very much for writing up this answer! If you could [edit] in references to sources that support these lines of argument, it would make this answer more valuable, and more compliant with the question's request for references. I don't get your concluding question; does it advance your answer, or is it a follow-up? If the former, please [edit] in how. If the latter, please delete it from here and consider posting it as a new question.

Answer (score 1):

one thing that I wish to acknowledge that I hope won't cause a stir,  I am Christian, but I like to expand my knowledge when possible.

from what I know, God Created all things, which would mean that he could destroy all things. but I have never seen anywhere that God Created himself.

Malachi 3:6 "For I am the LORD, I do not change..." (NKJ)

I found this Quote on a website called [Judaism in a Nutshell](http://www.torah.org/learning/basics/nutshell/part2.html#) (First Paragraph of Point 1, last 2 sentences)

> Additionally, absolute being means that His existence is unchanging. God never becomes "more" or "less" in any way; He is never different.

Comment: I apologize, but how is quoting another Religious Text, that says the exact same thing, off Topic?

Comment: Quoting non-Jewish sources is off topic no matter what it says. The topic is Judaism; everything else is not the topic.

Comment: how are those Sources not Jewish? my God is the Same God, The God of Abraham, the God of Isaac, The God of the Old Testament, I guess I need to Learn more about this, I don't mean any disrespect

Comment: It is the same God, but you have a book (Revelations in this case) which we do not believe to be representative of that God. The issue is if the source is Jewish, not if it talks about the same God. Even a heretic or a computer could talk _about_ our God, but we wouldn't think that is of much value.